# Как прописать ширину пустого span, чтобы он занимал всё свободное пространство?

Tags: css

Всем доброго времени суток! Никак не могу дойти до решения, как задать ширину span, который будет создавать отмеченную на скриншоте линию. Родителю (li) задала `display: flex`. Пробовала разные варианты `width` для всех трех элементов, но это не дало желаемого результата. Как сделать так, чтобы `span` занимал всё пустое место, между блюдом и ценой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<ul class="menu_list">
   <li class="list-item">
  <p class="dish-name">Chicken Breast</p>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <p class="dish-price">$19.50</p>
   </li>
   <li class="list-item">
  <p class="dish-name">Fresh Grilled Asparagus</p>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <p class="dish-price">$25.00</p>
   </li>
   <li class="list-item">
  <p class="dish-name">Pork-Stuffed Skins</p>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <p class="dish-price">$25.50</p>
   </li>
   <li class="list-item">
  <p class="dish-name">Grilled Chicken</p>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <p class="dish-price">$25.49</p>
   </li>
   <li class="list-item">
  <p class="dish-name">Steak Frites</p>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <p class="dish-price">$25.00</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex: 1 (тоже что и flex-grow: 1)` указывает на сколько элемент будет занимать места относительно свободного места в контейнере.

```css
.list-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.dots {
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #000;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="dish-name">Chicken Breast</p>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <p class="dish-price">$19.50</p>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="dish-name">Fresh Grilled Asparagus</p>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <p class="dish-price">$25.00</p>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="dish-name">Pork-Stuffed Skins</p>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <p class="dish-price">$25.50</p>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="dish-name">Grilled Chicken</p>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <p class="dish-price">$25.49</p>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="dish-name">Steak Frites</p>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <p class="dish-price">$25.00</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```